# Bootstrap 5.2 navbar seems to be returning major Performance drop within Core Web Vitals

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, lighthouse, core-web-vitals

I am currently attempting to build a page using HTML and Bootstrap 5.2, with a view to keeping Core Web Vitals scores as high as possible.

Upon building in the bootstrap navbar which contains an additional (second) dropdown level, I am seeing a consistent drop of between 20 and 27 points in the 'Performance' metric measured by Chrome Lighthouse, which I cannot understand.

The performance drop is not however entirely consistent with the addition of the second level dropdown in the navbar - it appears that adding in new navlinks will eventually lead to the tipping point where the metric for 'Largest Contentful Paint' increases considerably to anywhere around 8.0s, and the metric for 'Time to Interactive' jumps up to 8.6s.

I cannot unfortunately visualise what could be causing this problem - it occurs only with consistency when the navbar is built out. I am also aware that this may be one part of the larger picture when it comes to that Performance metric.

I have uploaded a working example at the following link:

https://www.minelands.com/test/all-template-with-second-level.html

I would really appreciate any insights from anyone out there who has experience with Core Web Vitals and Lighthouse.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the biggest issue is with [Cumulative Layout Shift](https://web.dev/cls/) (CLS)

[image: WebPageTest filmstrip]

You can see the layout issue clearly in the [WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/video/compare.php?tests=230206_AiDcAF_B0Z-r:3-c:0) filmstrip above. The page appears to render without styles between 4 and 5 seconds into page load (on a simulated slow connection to demonstrate the issue). Then the page renders with the expected styles at 5 seconds. This behavior is usually indicative of a stylesheet loading too slowly.

[image: WebPageTest waterfall]

The waterfall view for this page shows that the styles finish loading at around 5 seconds.

Towards the end of your HTML you have this code:

```html
<!--Preload Bootstrap 5.2 CSS-->
<link rel="preload" href="css/bootstrap5.2.min.css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'" />
<noscript><link rel="css/bootstrap5.2.min.css" href="styles.css"></noscript>
    

<!--Preload Custom CSS-->
<link rel="preload" href="css/custom-bootstrap5.css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'" />
<noscript><link rel="css/custom-bootstrap5.css" href="styles.css"></noscript>
```

These stylesheets are necessary for the initial layout of the page, so they should be loaded immediately. However, this technique delays when they start loading.

To fix it, move the stylesheets up to the document `<head>` and remove the preloading behavior, so that they load normally:

```html
<title>Page Title</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap5.2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom-bootstrap5.css">
```

Comment: That's crazy. Looks like i have misused the web.dev preloading solution here trying to mitigating the effects of the core and custom css coming down.

I definitely was not using webpagetest to view that waterfall indicator, or interpreting what is loading when. Thanks for this information.